# Get all resource files with lang extension

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have some resources like:

- JsResources.resx
- JsResources.fr.resx
- JsResources.en.resx

Where JsResources is my default resources, .fr.resx is the resource for french UICulture and .en.resx in the resource for english.

All is correctly binded with Razor

I want to retrieve all the resources and convert it into a Javascript resource.
I can get the default resx resource but not the two other (.fr.resx and .en.resx)

Here is my actual code:

```
var resourceDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            var lang = file.IncludedVirtualPath.Replace(".resx", string.Empty).Split('/').Last().Split('.').Last();

            var filename = file.IncludedVirtualPath.Replace(".resx", string.Empty).Split('/').Last().Split('.').First();

            var resource = GetType()
                .Assembly.GetManifestResourceNames()
                .FirstOrDefault(t => t.Contains($"{filename}.{lang}.resources"));

            if(resource != null)
            {
                using (var stream = GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resource))
                using (var reader = new ResourceReader(stream))
                {
                    foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in reader)
                    {
                        resourceDictionary.Add(entry.Key.ToString(), entry.Value.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
            var serializedDictionary = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(resourceDictionary);

            var javascript = $"var Resources = Resources || {{}};Resources.{lang}.{filename} = {serializedDictionary}";
```

If I do this:

```
var resourceList = GetType()
            .Assembly.GetManifestResourceNames().ToList();
```

I can get the default resource (JsResources.resx) but not the two others.

How can I achieve this ?

Thanks

Comment: The real question is: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: To use the ressources in my javascript file for adding some translation. And for learning purpose :)

Comment: The better way would be to load only the current language into JavaScript. Why add languages you do need. If the language is changed then reload.

Comment: What you are trying to do is kind of outside of the scope of resource files.